# Is mediainfo.dll compatible with UWP?

Tags: uwp, mediainfo

I want to write a program that uses mediainfo.dll. I use MediaInfoDLL.cs for getting video file information such as Size, Duration, etc. When I select a video file with filepicker, the open method of MediInfoLib namespace does not return video file information.
I try it with WinForms and it worked.
Do you know the problem is UWP file permission or MediaInfo UWP campatibility?

Comment: Could you give an example of the code you used that isn't working?

Comment: `mediainfo.dll` isn't compatible with `uwp` *but* there's a wrapper that may work [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaInfo.DotNetWrapper/) and or [here is a better one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaInfo.Wrapper/)

Comment: I used these wrappers but all of fields that returned after opening files were null or empty. So I used the MediaInfoDLL.cs that downloaded with mediainfo dll package. but when I use same code with winforms application everything worked

Comment: oh, you said it ISN't compatible

Comment: From MediaInfo developers: we didn't find a quick method for loading a DLL in UWP and ended to use a static version of MediaInfoLib in our MediaInfo UWP version, you could check [our repo](https://github.com/MediaArea/MediaInfo/tree/master/Project/MSVC2017/MediaInfo_UWP) for how a UWP project can interface with the static lib.